# In NodeJS How to access request headers from Mongoose virtual?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm working with NodeJS to create REST API. With the help of Mongoose, I'm interacting with the backend. I wrote below virtual to perform some action for each "find" call.

```
commentSchema.virtual('userLiked', {
  ref: 'CommentReaction',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'commentId',
  options: {
    match: doc => {
      const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
      const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_KEY);
      return { creator: decodedToken.userId }
    }
  },
  count: true
});
```

In above code, I'm trying to access the request headers to get the user Id and perform some action. How can I access request from the virtual in Mongoose?

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to resolve the problem using [localStorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/localStorage) npm. 
Using it, in the controller's function, where the request is available, I'm setting the "authorization" in localStorage as in below code:

```
exports.fetchCommentsForNews = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.headers.authorization != null) {
    localStorage.setItem('auth', req.headers.authorization);
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem('auth', '');
  }
  .
  .
  .
}
```

And in the schema's virtual code, I'm fetching the auth from localStorage as below:

```
commentSchema.virtual('userLikedCount', {
  ref: 'CommentReaction',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'commentId',
  options: {
    match: doc => {
      let userId = -1;
      let auth = localStorage.getItem('auth');
      if (auth != '') {
        const decodedToken = Util.decodeToken(auth);
        userId = decodedToken.userId;
      }

      return { creator: userId }
    }
  },
  count: true
});
```